# Is Chrome caching css transitions and if so, how to disable it

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, chromium

I feel like my transitions perform better after i played them a few times - I guess that this is caused by chrome caching the transition - Is that the case?
If so, how can I disable the cache for debugging reasons?

Thank you in advance.